# What is the right regex to match a relative path to an image file?

Tags: perl

I have this path `../../Capture.jpg`. So far I've figured out this incomplete regex: '[../]+'. I want to check if user puts in the right path like `../../image file name`. The file extensions can be jpg, png, ..

Comment: What exactly do you consider "the right path"? Existing file? Just random path matching your FS specs? Existing directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [../]+ is not sufficient or correct for the job at hand, if you REALLY want to match a bunch of ../ at the start of a filename.

It's not completely clear what you want to do exactly, but the following will match one or more ../ at the start of a string:

```
    /^((?:\.\.\/)+)/
```

basically:

^ to anchor to the start of the string being tested - will not match any ../ INSIDE the string

( and the balancing ) at the end: capture the contents within. All your ../../ will be available in a variable called $1

then I'm using (?: ) to wrap the next content. This groups the bit inside, but does NOT save the value inside a $1, $2, etc. More information soon...

The REAL pattern of interest is

```
    \.\.\/
```

Since . and / are magic characters, they need 'escaping' with backslash. This tells Perl that the . and / do NOT have a special meaning at this point.

I've used the (?: ) wrapper to group them together, so that the + operates on all 3 characters of interest. The + operator means "one or more repetitions".

So, my pattern will match one or more repetitions of ../ which are anchored to the start of the string. Furthermore, the exact contents matched will be available in $1 if you are interested in doing something with that (eg count how many ../ you have)

Please ask if you have further questions, or I have misunderstood your goals.

EDIT: to suit your new requirements, and add a bit of bonus:

```
    m!^\.\./\.\./(([^/]+)\.([^.]+))$!
```

Note first that I've used m!pattern! instead of /pattern/. Firstly, if Perl sees /pattern/ it assumes it's m/pattern/ but you can use an alternative character to wrap the patterns. This is useful if you actually want to use / in your pattern without having to go nuts with backslashes.

so:

^ exactly match only from the start

followed by exactly ../../

next I've used ( ) wrappers to capture the bits following. Explanation after...

ignoring the ( and ) now:

[^/]+ one or more repetitions (+) of any character that isn't /

. literally a dot - the one before the extension

[^./]+ one or more repetitions of any character that isn't . or /

Notice how the [^/]+ allows for any character including . but prevents another directory part from sneaking in. Thus, the filename could be foo.bar.jpg and it will be collected properly.

Notice how [^./]+ allows for any character in the extension except a dot - and also excluding / to prevent another directory segment from sneaking in.

Finally, $ is used to ensure we've reached the end of the pattern.

as for the captures:

$1 will contain all of foo.bar.jpg

$2 will contain foo.bar

$3 will contain jpg (not .jpg) but I'll leave it up to you to figure out what to change if you wish to capture the dot as well.

FINALLY - in a typical script, you might do something like:

```
    if($filename =~ m!^\.\./\.\./(([^/]+)\.([^./]+))$!) {
        print "You correctly entered ../../$1 giving basename=$2 and extension=$3 - Bravo!\n";
    }
    else {
        print "you've failed to read the instructions properly\n";
    }
```

As a bonus, I even tested that, and found 2 spolling mistaiks you'll never have to see

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert relative file paths to md links ... 
# file paths and names with letters , nums - and _ s supported
$str =~ s! (\.\.\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/\\]*)[\/\\]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)) ! [$3]($1) !gm
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care the path prefix, use:
  `$path =~ /\.(jpg|png)$/`
or
  `substr($path, -4) ~~ ['.jpg', '.png']`

With exactly '../../', use:
  `$path =~ m!^\.\./\.\./[^/]*\.(jpg|png)$!`

With any number of '../'s, use:
  `$path =~ m!^(\.\./)*[^/]*\.(jpg|png)$!`

Comment: I'd remove the smartmatch, it yields a `experimental` warning in more recent perl versions. If you want to use it, take a module. and why aren't using `qw` ?

Comment: There're only 2 items in the list. I usually use `qw()` if there're 4 items or more, and use `('..')` if there's only 1 item. I use `qw()` or `('..')` ramdomly if there're 2 or 3 items. I see no strong reasons why I must choose one instead of the other.
Did you vote down my answer because I use `~~` and `''`? Come on, they're still correct answers.. ^^|

Comment: actually, I downvoted just because of `~~`, as it yields a warning. The other is just a style issue, I wouldn't donvote because of that.